# PNP circuit - The Art of Electronics

Tags: pnp

I was reading the BJT section of *The Art of Electronics* on page 77 Figure 2.10.B.

Shouldn't the divider voltage sit at 14.4 V rather than 11.6 V? the opposite what the author mentioned. Since if <sub>3</sub> is in saturation, the base voltage of <sub>3</sub> should be ~0.6 V lower than the collector which is 14.4 V.

> The “divider” formed by <sub>2</sub> <sub>3</sub> may be confusing: <sub>3</sub>’s job is to keep <sub>3</sub> off when <sub>2</sub> is off; and when <sub>2</sub> pulls its collector low, most of its collector current comes from <sub>3</sub>’s base (because only ∼0.6 mA of the 4.4 mA collector current comes from <sub>3</sub> - make sure you understand why).
> That is, <sub>3</sub> does not have much effect on <sub>3</sub>’s saturation. Another way to say it is that the divider would sit at about +11.6 V (rather than +14.4 V), were it not for <sub>3</sub>’s base-emitter diode, which consequently gets most of <sub>2</sub>’s collector current. In any case, the value of <sub>3</sub> is not critical and could be made larger; the tradeoff is slower turn-off of <sub>3</sub>, owing to capacitive effects.<sup>12</sup>
> [image: Switching the high side of a load returned to ground.]
>
> **Figure 2.10.** Switching the high side of a load returned to ground.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>12) But don’t make it too small: <sub>3</sub> would not switch at all if <sub>3</sub> were reduced to 100 Ω (why?). We were surprised to see this basic error in an instrument, the rest of which displayed circuit design of the highest sophistication.</sup>

Comment: The text says that the divider does sit at 14.4V. Without Q3's diode, it would go to 11.6V. Or am I the one misreading it?

Comment: @SredniVashtar I guess I misread it. If that's the case then that makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: Question about the footnote: [Why would the transistor not switch?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/206730/29811)

Comment: @CL, if R3 was below about 140 R then the R3 and R2 potential divider would not put a voltage lower than 14.4 V on Q3's base and would not forward-bias Q3. I've said 'potential divider' but actually the circuit designer wants to stop R3 and R2 being able to be one - Q3's base-emitter diode should be clamping it out of dividerland. When I've used this circuit, I've used something like 47 K for R3 and R2 = (14.3V-0.3V)/5mA = 2800 R ~= 2700 R. (Obviously the 5 mA depends on the actual transistor and its load.)

Comment: @TonyM THANK you for explaining this! That makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text clearly states that the base-emitter junction of Q3 dominates the voltage across R3. If Vcc supply is +15 volts, this 'locks' the voltage at the base of Q3 at +15-.6, or about 14.4 volts.
 The 0.6 volt B-E drop is an average, as bjt transistors (NPN and PNP) have a B-E drop of about .55volts to .65 volts, depending on its beta and the manufactures needs.
 Notice the comment that R3 could be increased a great deal, to 10K perhaps. The only minor penalty would be a slower response due to transistor capacitance. R1, R2 and R3 could also be lower by 50%, increasing the response speed of the circuit, but at the small penalty of a higher 'ON' current.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understood the concept I just misread the part where it says " the divider would sit at 11.6v without were it not for Q3 base-emitter diode" 
It's clear now.